# Delphi subclass constructor override

Tags: delphi

I have the following classes declared in a single file:

```
type
 TCongruence = class(TObject)
  private
   a, b, n, numClass: integer;
   solutions, vals: TSolutions;
   hasSolutions: boolean;
   function divides(a, b: integer): boolean;
   function modulo(a, b: integer): integer;
  public
   constructor Create(a, b, n: integer); virtual;
   function getSolutions: TSolutions; virtual;
   function gcdExtended(p, q: integer): TSolutions;
   class function getGCD(u, v: integer): integer;
   property valA: integer read a;
   property valB: integer read b;
   property valN: integer read n;
   property getClass: integer read numClass;
   property hasSol: boolean read hasSolutions;
 end;

type
 TConguenceSystem = class(TCongruence)
  private
   system: array of TCongruence;
  public
   constructor Create(a: array of TCongruence); override;
   function getSolutions: integer; override;
 end;
```

The second one as you can see is a subclass because I need to use all the functions implemented in the `TCongruence` class. I have declared the constructor virtual so that I can call the override on the descendant.

Is that correct? Do I have to remove the virtual/override and simply use the constructor like this? (below)

```
constructor Create(a: array of TCongruence);
```

I guess that in this case I am hiding the father's constructor. I have declared this constructor:

```
constructor TConguenceSystem.Create(a: array of TCongruence);
var i: integer;
begin

 SetLength(system, length(a)); // private var system: array of TCongruence
 for i := Low(a) to High(a) do
  begin
   system[i] := a[i];
  end;

 solutions := false;

end;
```

Comment: Doesn't look correct hierarchy for me. `getSolutions` also has changed signature

Comment: i think that is correct, i use the same shema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you intend to override behaviour of a method **with the same signature** in a descendent class then you must declare it `virtual` in the base class and the descendent class would then use `override`.

If, however, you wish to introduce a new method with a *different signature* then you must use the `overload` directive *if you are declaring the method within the same class*.  This simply allows re-use of the same method name for what are, effectively, entirely different methods with different signatures. For example :

```
 TCongruence = class(TObject)
   public
     constructor Create(a : integer); overload;
     constructor Create(a, b, n: integer); overload;
 end;
```

If you are declaring a new method in a descendent class, however, with a different signature then none of these decorations are required.

```
 TCongruence = class(TObject)
   public
     constructor Create(a, b, n: integer);
 end;

 TCongruenceSystem = class(TCongruence)
   public
     constructor Create(a: array of TCongruence);
 end;
```

The above is fine - you are not overriding the original constructor, you are simply introducing a new one with a new signature.  Since the latter belongs to a new class with a different name there is no ambiguity and `overload` is not required. You can even access the ancestor methods in the usual way here :

```
 TCongruence = class(TObject)
   private
     Fa, Fb, Fn : integer;
   public
     constructor Create(a, b, n: integer);
 end;

 TCongruenceSystem = class(TCongruence)
   private
     FArr : array of TCongruence;
   public
     constructor Create(a: array of TCongruence);
 end;

constructor TCongruence.Create(a, b, n: integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Fa := a;
  Fb := b;
  Fn := n;
end;

constructor TCongruenceSystem.Create(a: array of TCongruence);
var
  c : TCongruence;
  i : integer;
begin
  inherited Create(a[0].Fa, a[1].Fb, a[2].Fn);
  SetLength(FArr, Length(a));
  i := 0;
  for c in a do begin
    FArr[i] := c;
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

Without the `overload` directive, however, the following would not be allowed :

```
var
  cs : TCongruenceSystem;
begin
  cs := TCongruenceSystem.Create(1, 2, 3); 
end.
```

since `TCongruenceSystem` is hiding the base class `Create` which takes three `integer` arguments.  If you allow the `overload`, however :

```
 TCongruence = class(TObject)
   private
     Fa, Fb, Fn : integer;
   public
     constructor Create(a, b, n: integer); overload;
 end;

 TCongruenceSystem = class(TCongruence)
   private
     FArr : array of TCongruence;
   public
     constructor Create(a: array of TCongruence); overload;
 end;
```

Then the above call of `cs := TCongruenceSystem.Create(1, 2, 3);` would be allowed and the ancestor constructor would be used to build the descendent class.

These approaches can be combined, for example :

```
 TCongruence = class(TObject)
   public
     constructor Create(a : integer); overload; virtual; {overridable}
     constructor Create(a, b, n: integer); overload;     {only in base}
 end;

 TCongruenceSystem = class(TCongruence)
   public
     constructor Create(a:integer); overload; override;  {overrides parent}
     constructor Create(a: string); overload;            {introduce new}
 end;
```

In the case of the constructor you are introducing a method with a different set of parameters so this is allowed.  In the case of `getSolutions`, however, the function is takes no parameters and differs only in the return type.  An overloaded method needs to have a different parameter set, however, so this type of mutation is not allowed in a descendent class.  `getSolutions` in the descendent class would need to take a different name if you intend it to also be a parameterless function with a different return type.

Comment: I got it thank you. See my edited question, I have written the implementation of TCongruenceSystem. Do I need to call the inherited Create in the subclass?

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi You don't need to call it - it depends on what behaviour you want.